# Getting different typeof for nearly same input in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am putting nearly same input, but the typeof of the following 2 calculations is different, can someone point out why?

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

console.log(typeof 1/0);
console.log(typeof (1/0));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I believe in both cases the answer is 1/0 => 'Infinity', so why am I getting different results.

Comment: It's the difference between `(typeof 1) / 0` and `typeof (1/0)`

Comment: NaN, number -> You can click 'Run Code Snippet' and can get answer.

Comment: @SLePort: 1/0 => Infinity, typeof Infinity is 'number'. That's what it is giving. I was interested in 1st part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript operator precedence:  [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

As you can see, the precedence level for `typeof` is 16, whereas the precedence level for division is 14.  This means, in the absense of parenthesis, `typeof` will be evaluated first.  The relevant operator precedence levels are:

- Grouping: 20
- Typeof: 16
- Division: 14

We evaluate your expressions as:

```
typeof 1/0   --> "number"/0      --> "NaN"
typeof (1/0) --> typeof Infinity --> "number"
```

On the first line, `typeof` has a higher precedence, so we evaluate `typeof 1` first.  This evaluates to "number", which cannot be divided by zero, so we get NaN.

On the second line, `(1/0)` is evaluated first because [Grouping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) has the highest precedence (20).  It evaluates to NaN, which has the type "number".

Answer (score 1):

see the first statement as (type of 1) /0